# Populate drop-downlist from JSON to PHP

Tags: php, json, sql-server

Below is my JSON result

[image]

When I want to populate the "factoryList" in to PHP drop-down list, I get the weird result. Below is the result

[image]

and below is my current php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php

$url = 'http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/factoryList'; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$characters = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

foreach ($characters->factoryList as $character) {
     echo '<select class="form-control" name="Fac_ID" class="form-control">';
     echo "<option value='$character->facID'>$character->facName</option>";
    echo "</select>";
}

?>

</html>
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Please repeat the option the tag not the select tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the generation of the `select` outside the loop:

```
echo '<select class="form-control" name="Fac_ID" class="form-control">';
foreach ($characters->factoryList as $character) {
     echo "<option value='$character->facID'>$character->facName</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: sorry for interrupt you mate, can you solve this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819513/populate-2nd-drop-down-list-based-on-1st-drop-down-using-api-json