# Populate 2nd drop-down list based on 1st drop-down using API JSON

Tags: php, json, sql-server, ajax, web-services

I want to display data at 2nd drop-down list base on data chosen from 1st drop-down list.
I used AJAX to get display data at 2nd drop downlist.

Below is the JSON result if facID = F09

[image]

Below is the AJAX code at where the drop-down list is located

```
<script>
    function getroom(val) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../room_scheduler/room_scheduler.php",
        data:'factory_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
          $("#room-list").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

and below is the room_scheduler.php

```
    <?php

    require_once "../../../config/configPDO.php";
    require_once "../../../config/check.php";

    //retrieve json
    $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/roomList?facID='" . $_POST['factory_id'] . "'";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $characters = json_decode($data);

        if(!empty($_POST["factory_id"])) {

            echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
            foreach ($characters->roomList as $character) {
            echo "<option value='$character->roomId'>$character->Room_Desc</option>";
            }

        }

    ?>
```

The result if, if in the 1st drop-down list I choose F09, there's no data display at the 2nd drop-down list. Can I know what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the ajax call is happening? And have you checked the response from it?

Comment: Already solve by my self. Anyways, thanks dude!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've solved it. If you think the answer could be useful to others, you can post it as an answer to your own question. Otherwise you may as well just delete the question.

Comment: I already post my answer, btw, Can you please check this questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833039/php-json-how-know-if-data-json-is-empty-or-not

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, this question already solved by myself

```
    <?php

    require_once "../../../config/configPDO.php";
    require_once "../../../config/check.php";

    $factory_id = $_POST["factory_id"];

    //retrieve json
    $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/roomList?facID=$factory_id";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $characters = json_decode($data);

        if(!empty($factory_id)) {

            echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
            foreach ($characters->roomList as $character) {
            echo "<option value='$character->roomId'>$character->roomDesc</option>";
            }

        }


    ?>
```