# PHP / JSON: How do I know if JSON data is empty or not?

Tags: php, json, sql-server

Currently, I create a table that displays data from the database (JSON). In that table, I want to check is the data exists or not. Let's say if data is empty, I want to display "No booking data available at these moments".

The problem is, I don't know how to check the existing data. For now, if the data is empty, the table appears with `<th>` only and no words "No booking data available at these moments".

Below is my current code:

```
  <?php

  //retrieve json
  $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayAdminBookingDashboard?adminEmail=$Email";
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($data);

  if(empty($json)){
    echo "<div class='card bg-light'>";
    echo "<div class='card-body double' style='height: 400px;>";
    echo "<h4 class='card-title'><i>No booking data available at this moments</i></h4>";

  }else{

    echo "<div class='card bg-light'>";
    echo "<div class='card-body double' style='height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;'>";
      echo "<h4 class='card-title'>All Booking</h4>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead>";
          echo "<tr>";
              echo "<th>#</th>
              <th>Requester</th>
              <th>Factory</th>
              <th>Room</th>
              <th>Purpose</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody >";

          foreach ($json->bookingList as $row) {

            $status=$row->status;

            if($status=="Approve"){

                $color="color:green";

            }else if($status=="Pending"){

              $color="color:blue";

            }else{

              $color="color:red";

            }

            echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->bookNo. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->requestedBy. "</td>";                                              
              echo "<td>" . $row->facID. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->roomName. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->desc. "</td>";   
              echo "<td style='$color'><strong>" . $status ."</strong></td>";
              echo "<td>";
              echo "<a class='btn-view btn-primary btn-sm' href='../../view_booking/admin/view_booking_admin.php?Book_No=". $row->bookNo ."' data-toggle='tooltip'>View</a>";
              echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

          }

          echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table><br>";  
      echo "</div>";
    echo "<div>";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Could you display a var_dump of $json  when no booking data is available?
Maybe the json is actually not empty even in the case there are not booking data.

Comment: Can i know where in which line i need to put var_dump?

Comment: Also added your json response. Try count json count($json); if count is greater then do something else No booking data available at these moments

Comment: after $json = json_decode($data);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php

  //retrieve json
  $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayAdminBookingDashboard?adminEmail=$Email";
  $data = @file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($data);

  if($json === FALSE && empty($json)){
    echo "<div class='card bg-light'>";
    echo "<div class='card-body double' style='height: 400px;>";
    echo "<h4 class='card-title'><i>No booking data available at this moments</i></h4>";

  }else{

    echo "<div class='card bg-light'>";
    echo "<div class='card-body double' style='height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;'>";
      echo "<h4 class='card-title'>All Booking</h4>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead>";
          echo "<tr>";
              echo "<th>#</th>
              <th>Requester</th>
              <th>Factory</th>
              <th>Room</th>
              <th>Purpose</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody >";

          foreach ($json->bookingList as $row) {

            $status=$row->status;

            if($status=="Approve"){

                $color="color:green";

            }else if($status=="Pending"){

              $color="color:blue";

            }else{

              $color="color:red";

            }

            echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->bookNo. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->requestedBy. "</td>";                                              
              echo "<td>" . $row->facID. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->roomName. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->desc. "</td>";   
              echo "<td style='$color'><strong>" . $status ."</strong></td>";
              echo "<td>";
              echo "<a class='btn-view btn-primary btn-sm' href='../../view_booking/admin/view_booking_admin.php?Book_No=". $row->bookNo ."' data-toggle='tooltip'>View</a>";
              echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

          }

          echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table><br>";  
      echo "</div>";
    echo "<div>";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: A good answer also explains what was changed and why to assist the OP and future viewers understand as opposed to just copying code and trying to find what has changed.

Comment: $json === FALSE is redundant to empty($json). I think the issue is that $json has actually some content, even when no booking data available.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my question. I just add "bookingList" at the empty json

```
 <?php

  //retrieve json
  $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayAdminBookingDashboard?adminEmail=$Email";
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($data);

  if(empty($json->bookingList)){
    echo "<div class='card bg-light'>";
    echo "<div class='card-body double' style='height: 400px;>";
    echo "<h4 class='card-title'><i>No booking data available at this moments</i></h4>";

  }else{

    echo "<div class='card bg-light'>";
    echo "<div class='card-body double' style='height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;'>";
      echo "<h4 class='card-title'>All Booking</h4>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead>";
          echo "<tr>";
              echo "<th>#</th>
              <th>Requester</th>
              <th>Factory</th>
              <th>Room</th>
              <th>Purpose</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody >";

          foreach ($json->bookingList as $row) {

            $status=$row->status;

            if($status=="Approve"){

                $color="color:green";

            }else if($status=="Pending"){

              $color="color:blue";

            }else{

              $color="color:red";

            }

            echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->bookNo. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->requestedBy. "</td>";                                              
              echo "<td>" . $row->facID. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->roomName. "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->desc. "</td>";   
              echo "<td style='$color'><strong>" . $status ."</strong></td>";
              echo "<td>";
              echo "<a class='btn-view btn-primary btn-sm' href='../../view_booking/admin/view_booking_admin.php?Book_No=". $row->bookNo ."' data-toggle='tooltip'>View</a>";
              echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

          }

          echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table><br>";  
      echo "</div>";
    echo "<div>";
  }

  ?>
```